# How to delete entire column if it is Empty

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have columns 
Row 1 is heading..

```
IF Column C doesn't have data in entire column then delete C D E F
IF Column D doesn't have data in entire column then delete D E F
IF Column E doesn't have data in entire column then delete E F
IF Column F doesn't have data in entire column then delete F
```

Same way for heading NN's

```
IF Column G doesn't have data in entire column then delete G H I J K L M N 
IF Column H doesn't have data in entire column then delete H I J K L M N 
IF Column I doesn't have data in entire column then delete I J K L M N 
IF Column J doesn't have data in entire column then delete J K L M N 
IF Column K doesn't have data in entire column then delete K L M N 
IF Column L doesn't have data in entire column then delete L M N 
IF Column M doesn't have data in entire column then delete M N 
IF Column N doesn't have data in entire column then delete N


A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R
TI1 TE2 TT1 TT2 TT3 TT4 NN1 NN2 NN3 NN4 NN5 NN6 NN7 NN8 CMT K2  K3  
BLAH    BLAH
```

Comment: I see contradiction: every column has headers. How `Column C doesn't have data in entire column` may be possible?

Comment: It 99.999% it will have data but it sun rises from other direction it might have data in there, if C doesn't have data then 100% D E F won't have data in it.

Comment: Pal, if column DOES have headers - it can't be entire empty! provide exact condition please.

Comment: Header doesn't count sorry, check everything below headers.

Comment: @Mowgli (just doing a review of all Q/As that I have contributed to) Did either of the answers given answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

I would do this by adding in an extra row to work things out (you can always hide it later).

Suppose your headings are in row1, then add in an extra (helper) row in row2.

- In C2, put in the following formula (replace `C30` with an appropriate value for you):

  `=COUNTA(C3:C30)`
- In D2, put in the following formula:

  `=IF(C2=0,0,COUNTA(D3:D30))`
- Drag that formula across to E & F
- Redo C's formula in G
- Redo D's formula in H and drag across to N

... Etc.

Now it's just a matter of writing a very simple macro to delete any column where row2's value = 0.

That seemed like the easiest way to do it for me, but there are MANY other ways.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

This macro does your first bit - the second stage will be very similar.

You'll need to chage the `5`s to the length of your table.

`GoTo` isn't generally liked but I've used it in this code.

```
Sub firstbit()

If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C5")) = 0 Then
    Excel.ActiveSheet.Range("C2:F5").clearcontents
    GoTo FirstStageComplete:
End If
If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D5")) = 0 Then
    Excel.ActiveSheet.Range("D2:F5").clearcontents
    GoTo FirstStageComplete:
End If
If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E5")) = 0 Then
    Excel.ActiveSheet.Range("E2:F5").clearcontents
    GoTo FirstStageComplete:
End If
If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F5")) = 0 Then
    Excel.ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F5").clearcontents
End If
FirstStageComplete:

End Sub
```